# jQuery animate expand proportionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm now in problem about how to **animate** function in jQuery to expand proportionally. Normally, it expand one-sided only just like expand to bottom or expand to right.

What I want is to expand proportionally left-right-top-bottom by using animate.

[image]

Following is my coding. What I said above, it expand to bottom only.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theFrame = $("#FrmPatient", parent.document.body);
    theFrame.animate({width: 650, height: 485}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You need to clarify what you think the problem here is, because as far as I can tell, the code is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/ZYSLK/

Comment: Nope. When you run this code, it expand to left and bottom only. Right? What I want is to expand to left, right, top and bottom like LightBox effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="frame"></div>

#frame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #999;
}

$(function() {
    var w = 400, h = 400;
    $("#frame").animate({
        width: w,
        height: w,
        marginLeft: -w/2,
        marginTop: -h/2
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GVj83/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to animate the *left* and *top* properties as well.  If the original width and height of the box are (w0, h0) and the expanded ones are (w1, h1), animate *left* to *left-(w1-w0)/2*, and *top* to *top-(h1-h0)/2*.  Note that would only work with absolute or relative positioning.