# Expand div from parent div to center viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I was able to [expand the div from the center of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902123/expand-div-from-center-of-viewport/) but now, I would like to expand the div starting for the "click me" box creating an effect/illusion that a box is coming from it growing all the way to the center viewport.

It should follow the click me box like let's say the click me box is at the top, when the user clicks on it it should be coming from the top as well then growing up to the center viewport.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5w8orvp/1/) and a sample code from the JSFiddle as well. (Note that the `<p>` are just to show content that will make the body have a scrollbar)

**HTML**

```
<div class="growme">test</div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<div class="box"><h3>click me</h3></div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
.box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.box').on('click', function () {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('.growme').animate({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        opacity: 1,
    }, 'normal');
});

$('.growme').on('click', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        opacity: 0,
    }, 'normal', function(){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    });
});
```

In case you are wondering what the output would look like, I was able to find [this site](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ZoomSlider/) that does the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want to do  is make the `.growme` box grow from the center of the `.box` box, instead of from the center of the screen, what you need to do is to reset its position each time that you are going to open it.

How to do that? Calculate the position of the `.box` element within the viewport by using [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (to obtain the position of `.box` within the document) and [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) (to get the value of the scrollbars). In pseudocode, it would be something like this:

```
position = element_height + element_offset - window_scroll
```

Once you have that, it is really simple:

1. Update the CSS for `.growme` so the box is initially in the horizontal center:

   ```
   .growme {
       background-color: #990000;
       height: 0;
       width: 0;
       position: fixed;
       opacity: 0;
       top:0;
       left:50%;
       margin:0;
   }
   ```
2. Get the target position for `.growme` (with the formula above):

   ```
   100 + $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
   ```
3. Place `.growme` in the target position.

   ```
   $(".growme").css({ top: (100 + $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px"});
   ```
4. Animate `.growme` so it goes to the top-left corner and its width and height occupy 100%.

   ```
   $('.growme').animate({
           width: '100%',
           height: '100%',
           left:0,
           top:0,
           opacity: 1,
       }, 'normal');
   ```

And that should do the trick (for the shrinking process, you'd need to calculate the target top for the animation, see the code below). Here is the code (I commented the `overflow:hidden` part to avoid the resize of the viewport when the scrollbars disappear):

```js
$('.box').on('click', function () {

  // set the .growme div at the center of the .box div
  $(".growme").css({ top: (100 + $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px"});

  //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  
  $('.growme').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    left:0,
    top:0,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 'normal');
});

$('.growme').on('click', function () {
  
  // calculate the target goal for the top position
  var goal = (100 + $(".box").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  
  $(this).animate({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    left:"50%",
    top: goal,
    opacity: 0,
  }, 'normal', function(){
    //$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
  });
});
```

```css
.growme {
  background-color: #990000;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin:0;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="growme">test</div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<div class="box"><h3>click me</h3></div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
```

This solution works perfectly to start growing the `.growme` div from the center of the `.box`... But there's a catch: the growth is not proportional to the  `.box` div, but to the viewport proportion, that may not be the same as the `.box` (3x2).

One possible solution for this is to set `.growme` so it "mimics" the position and size of `.box`. It will still not grow proportionally to its size, but it will almost look like it:

```js
$('.box').on('click', function () {

  $(".growme").css({ top: ($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px", left: "calc(50% - 150px)", width:300, height:200, zIndex:2 });

  //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('.growme').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    left:0,
    top:0,
    opacity: 1,
  }, 'normal');
});

$('.growme').on('click', function () {
  var goaltop = ($(".box").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) + "px";
  var goalleft = window.innerWidth/2 - 150;
  $(this).animate({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    left:goalleft,
    top: goaltop,
    opacity: 0,
  }, 'normal', function(){
    //$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    $(this).css("z-index",-1)
  });
});
```

```css
.growme {
  background-color: #990000;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #999;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="growme">test</div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<div class="box"><h3>click me</h3></div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
```

If you still want to make it grow proportionally, you could check [this question and the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673268/jquery-animate-expand-proportionally), but notice that it would require additional calculations in your case (to determine if the viewport is in portrait/landscape mode and perform the effect accordingly).

Comment: This, my friend, is insane!!! Just PERFECT!! Thank you so much @Alvaro Montoro!! I've been coding this for days! You're the best!

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory it should work by using the CSS transition and changing the box's width and height, then centring it and making the div `fixed` to keep it in the middle of the page... here is my try tho it's not perfect

have a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/tp24e5fq/1/)

```js
$('.box').on('click', function () {
    $('body').toggleClass('nooverflow');
    $(this).toggleClass('grow');
});
```

```css
.nooverflow {overflow:hidden;}

.box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    background-color: #999;
    transition:0.3s;
}
.box.grow {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<div class="box"><h3>click me</h3></div>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
<p>adsadsad</p>
```

Some points to consider:

- no smooth transition from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`
- box has absolute positioning, make sure that doesn't break your layout, you might want to add a placeholder div for space preservation
- add cross-browser where necessary (transition, transform, opacity etc)

Edit: I just noticed that when the box is above the fold, the transition is better, but when it is below the fold (viewport height) the box goes to the center instantly then grows

Comment: Thanks @Aziz, close enough though. Yes, I agree that having a `position:fixed` will not give you smooth transitioning. I was able to stumble upon (http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ZoomSlider/) which has the same output that I was looking for.

Comment: no problem, just checked the tympanus demo, pretty slick. this article explains it - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/06/zoom-slider/

Comment: Yeah.. the transitions are soooo smooooth! But the problem is that I won't/can't use that plugin since it does not meet my requirements. Let's just say, I do not want to edit/customize that plugin just to fit it in my requirements. That's the purpose on why I want to build something like it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to accomplish what you wanted to do, however I must note that there may be a trade off involving the positioning of the box itself. In my solution, the box has a `fixed` position as default and therefore may succumb to some positioning difficulties.

In retrospect of this, here is the code that I have implemented which shows an initial box with a set width and height expanding outward into the entire page on click and back to it's default size and location upon a second click.

Here is the HTML code that I have written.

```
<body>
    <div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS code that I have written.

```
#box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code that I have written, it does most of the hard work so I've commented it liberally.

```
// On document loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Box starts not expanded
  var expanded = false;
  // On box click
  $('#box').on('click', function () {
    // If the box is not expanded
    if (!expanded) {
      // Animate the box
      $(this).animate({
        // Remove horizontal centering
        // This gives appearance of outward expansion
        left: '0',
        // Quotes on 'margin-left' for name errors
        'margin-left': '0',
        // Expand box to full page size
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      });
      // Box is now expanded
      expanded = true;
    }
    // If the box is expanded
    else {
      // Change box to default position
      // Animate the box
      $(this).animate({
        // Restore horizontal centering
        // This gives appearance of inward shrinking
        left: '50%',
        // Quotes on 'margin-left' for name errors
        'margin-left': '-150px',
        // Expand box to normal size
        width: '300px',
        height: '200px'
      });
      // Box is now not expanded
      expanded = false;
    }
  });
});
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sdy90yt5/) is a JSFiddle I have created to show it working in action.

Comment: Thanks @Swiper-CCCVI. Though the problem is that when the body has content which will display a scroll bar, the div itself is still in a fixed position. (https://jsfiddle.net/sdy90yt5/1/).

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't have it both ways when it comes to an animation like this. If I do come across a solution for this problem, I will certainly let you know